# Is there a way to ask screen to start with terminal split in 3 parts with a different command running in each?

Tags: gnu-screen

I always start 3 terminals with a dev server in one, a python shell in the second one and a `cd` in the third one, ready for bash input.

I would like to have in my .bashrc a shortcut to set this up with one command: run `screen`, split it in 3 columns, and start a different command in each part of the screen.

How can I do that ?

EDIT: I already know I can make an alias to make `screen -c` and read from a specific config file, I'm just unsure of what to put in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use layouts in your screenrc

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STARTUP SCREENS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

layout new
split -v
split -v
screen htop
focus next
screen -t python python
focus next 
chdir /srv
screen -t dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split` command is what you're looking for. With no argument, it splits the screen in two horizontally.

Except "horizontally" can be confusing in this context, so to be more specific: it splits the screen into two panes such that the separator between the two panes is a horizontal line, which means the two panes are arranged vertically one over the other.

To split the screen the other way ("vertically"), pass `-v` to it. And to get three parts, you just need to split twice.

Once you have more than one pane, you can use `focus` to change which pane is current for the purpose of later commands. The command `focus next` moves forward (like control-A tab), while `focus prev` moves backward (like control-A shift-tab).

So in a new screen, you have one pane and it has focus. If you're using a custom config file, though, it's just open on the blank window `-`, so you need to start with the `screen` command to get an actual shell:

```
screen
```

Then you can split it:

```
split -v
```

Now you have two panes, but the second one is not focused and is showing the blank window `-`. You can fix that by moving to it and starting your Python shell:

```
focus next
screen python
```

Now split again to get a third pane.

```
split -v
```

Note that even though you're logically splitting one of the two panes, you wind up with three equal-sized panes (or as close as possible for your terminal size), not one half-screen and two quarter-screen panes.

Move to the new one:

```
focus next
```

Now you want to get a shell in a specific directory. One way to do that is to use the `chdir` command to change `screen`'s directory before starting the shell:

```
chdir /wherever
screen
```

But that technique doesn't work for me; my shell saves my working dir in a file every time I cd, and the last thing my .zshrc does is cd to the directory in that file. So the directory the parent process is in when the shell is started doesn't affect where I wind up inside the shell, and I have to use another mechanism. Another option is to start the shell and then send it a `cd` command to it:

```
screen
stuff "cd /wherever\n"
```

Use whichever works for you. And of course you can add `-t title` to the `screen` commands.

```
screen
split -v
focus next
screen -t python python
split -v
focus next
screen -t /somewhere
stuff "cd /somewhere\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$ cat s
screen -dm -S moo -t hello
screen  -S moo -X screen -t cruel
screen  -S moo -X screen -t world
screen  -S moo -p 0 -X stuff $'vim\r'
sleep 2
screen  -S moo -p 1 -X stuff $'watch dmesg\r'
sleep 2
screen  -S moo -p 2 -X stuff $'top\r'
```

Comment: No, it does not split the screen. It open several windows.

Answer (score -1):

Would [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html) be something of use to you?

From their site:

```
The goal of this project is to produce a useful tool for arranging terminals.
It is inspired by programs such as gnome-multi-term, quadkonsole, etc. in
that the main focus is arranging terminals in grids (tabs is the most common
default method, which Terminator also supports).
```

Comment: No. Terminator lacks of another feature that I value more than this.