# Launch or reattach a split GNU-screen, with each pane running its own command?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, tmux, gnu-screen

I want to be able to launch a command, like ./stats.sh, to open a screen (Or tmux, or whatever else if need be) that is either reattached if it already exists - or launched if it doesn't, running say, 'htop' in one pane, and 'dstat' in another.

I know you can do this by using ctrl+a | in an existing screen session, but I'd like to be able to do this all from a script that I can just run. Is such a thing possible?

Another way to phrase the question: Is it possible to launch a screen from the command line with multiple panes, each pane running its own command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked in different forms, but I'll reference those where appropriate.

First, to [attach to existing screen or create a new one if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433922/gnu-screen-connect-if-exists-create-if-not), use this:

```
screen -D -R -S namedscreen
```

Alternatively, you can test if a named screen exists and create one (detached) if not:

```
screen -S name -X select . || screen -dm -S name
```

For the rest of the scriting you want, you can [create windows and send commands to an existing screen session](https://superuser.com/questions/487271/is-there-a-way-to-ask-screen-to-start-with-terminal-split-in-3-parts-with-a-diff?rq=1):

```
screen -dm -S name -t window0
screen  -S name -X screen -t window1
screen  -S name -X screen -t window2
screen  -S name -p 0 -X stuff $'command 1\r'
screen  -S name -p 1 -X stuff $'command 2\r'
screen  -S name -p 2 -X stuff $'command 3\r'
```

Finally, [see this other post on how to do the same thing with `tmux`](https://superuser.com/questions/1176195/tmux-over-ssh-in-script/1176768#1176768).